# How to do MySQL update query in r

Tags: mysql, r, sql-update

In MySQL, what I did is:

```
update table set group = 1 where log(id) < 0
```

I wanna do same thing in R but I have no idea

What should I do?

Comment: There is a package called [sqldf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/sqldf.pdf).  Have a look at it.

Comment: `tab$group[log(tab$id) < 0] <- 1` or similar.

Comment: Check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130417/update-function-sqldf-r-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` in `R`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(tab)`), using the logical condition in 'i', we assign (`:=`) 1 to 'group' variable.  As this does in place, it would be much faster and efficient.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tab)[log(id) <0, group := 1]
```

Comment: you forgot to put log for the id.

Answer (score 1):

Using sqldf: You cannot use group as the variable name so im changing to catg.

```
sqldf(c("update table set catg = 1 where log(id) < 0", "select * from main.xy"))
```

Comment: You can put `group` in double quotes or enclose it in square brackets.

Comment: Hopefully i will be able to remember that from now on! Thanks